# AS3 loading external swf liberary single file

Tags: flash, external

I am facing long loading problem, otherwise keeping many swf(files) problem.

I have decoration items that exist in an external swf's liberary, when i need any one of the decoration item from it, I have to load the whole file first (which takes too long as there are many items in it). Is there a way that I can only ask for certain item(movieclip) from the liberary.

In othercase I will have to make 'n' number of files for every decoration item.

Thanks,
Najm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should separate your assets.swf to many swfs like:
assetsForStage1.swf
assetsForStage2.swf
assetsForStage3.swf
Where assetsForStage1.swf holds assets which your app usually needs at stage1 or some state of your app.

Comment: Yes I agree, It is what I believe I will have to, it will superfast their loading.... is there any other option ?